# Batch file RSA token converter

Tags: cmd

I'm a new to batch scripting. Im trying to write batch file where I can use the RSA token converter. How can I change the file name using the input of user login? The file name would change according to user: x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid, tatesting.txt. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
set /p a=
IF %a%==1 goto iPhone 
IF %a%==2 goto Android

:iPhone
set /p uname=Please enter user's Windows login:
pause
If "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
pushd \\test.com\Tokens
find %uname%
tokenconverter x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid -mobile -o tatesting.txt
:Error
echo "You did not enter user's name. Bye! Bye!"

GOTO END
:END
exit

:Android
set /p uname=Please enter user's Windows login:
pause
If "%uname%"=="" GOTO Error
pushd \\testing.com\Tokens
tokenconverter x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid -android -o tatesting.txt

:Error
echo "You did not enter user's name. Bye! Bye!"

GOTO END
:end

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO username is %username%
set /p uname=Please enter user's Windows login:
IF NOT DEFINED uname GOTO Error
:phone
set /p a="1) iPhone 2)Android ? "
IF "%a%"=="1" goto iPhone 
IF "%a%"=="2" goto Android
ECHO 1 or 2 only, please
GOTO phone

:iPhone
pushd \\test.com\Tokens
:: find %uname%
ECHO tokenconverter x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid -mobile -o tatesting.txt
popd
GOTO end

:Error
echo "You did not enter user's name. Bye! Bye!"
GOTO END

:Android
pushd \\testing.com\Tokens
ECHO tokenconverter x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid -android -o tatesting.txt
popd
GOTO END

:end
PAUSE
REM exit
GOTO :EOF
```

A few problems with your procedure.

A label is simply a marker. Batch simply continues execution with the next statement it encounters until it encounters a `goto` or `exit` reaches end-of-file.

You cannot duplicate labels.

The majority of your processing is the same in both instances, so I've re-arranged it to minimise code.

`username` is set by the system to contain a bag of potatoes. That might be easier to use.

You may prefer to use `choice` to select between the target devices. See `choice /?` from the prompt for documentation.

Since the user-input is freeform, it's safer (bu not bullet-proof) to use `if "..."=="..."...` because `"quoting a string"` process the string as a single item if it contains spaces (and you can't guarantee the the user isn't going to respond "war and peace".)

`PUSHD` pushes the current directory and jumps to the target directory. Are you sure about your targets?

You have no matching `popd`. I've inserted one, even though in the current application it appears redundant. A matter of "good form".

I have no knowledge of `tokenconverter` so I've just `ECHO`ed the lines. You'd need to remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate once you've verified that the instruction is correct.

I'v no idea what you mean by `find %uname%`. `FIND` locates a string within a file. What you are doing here is a mystery, so I've commented the `find` out. (`::` is easier to type than `REM`, does effectively the same job and is less intrusive visually)

I've simply `PAUSE`d at the end and commented-out your `EXIT` This allows you to see the `ECHO`ed *tokenconverter* commands. `EXIT` should terminate the batch by terminating the instance of `cmd`. This is a pain during debugging.

Comment: thank you for your response. I will try it and follow your advice.

Comment: Magoo, I'm trying to use the username inputted by the user and replace it with the filename. For example, user is billy, then token converter would use the file: x-rimdevice-billy.sdtid instead of x-rimdevice-tatesting.sdtid. Is there anyway to do that? Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did some tweaks and were able to do what I wanted.

```
@ECHO OFF
color 0a
SETLOCAL
set location1="\\test.com\tokens"
set location2="\\test.com\tokens\iPhone_tokens"
set location3="\\test.com\tokens\android_tokens"
ECHO username is %username%

set /p uname=Please enter user's Windows login:
IF NOT DEFINED uname GOTO Error
:phone
set /p a="1) iPhone 2)Android ? "
IF "%a%"=="1" goto iPhone 
IF "%a%"=="2" goto Android
ECHO 1 or 2 only, please
GOTO phone

:iPhone
pushd %location1%
:: find %uname%
tokenconverter x-rimdevice-%uname%.sdtid -mobile -o iPhone-%uname%.txt
move %location1%\iPhone-%uname%.txt %location2%\iPhone-%uname%.txt
popd
GOTO end

:Error
echo "You did not enter user's name. Bye! Bye!"
GOTO END

:Android
pushd %location1%
tokenconverter x-rimdevice-%uname%.sdtid -android -o android-%uname%.txt
move %location1%\iPhone-%uname%.txt %location3%\android-%uname%.txt
popd
GOTO END

:end
PAUSE
exit
```